# How do I create a spreadsheet that creates duplicates of a row, based on the answer to an inquiry on quantity

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet in Excel 2010 that creates duplicates of a row, based on the answer to a question on quantity.

For Example - my question would be, "How many pizza's do you have?"  Based on this response, a row of information gaining details on the pizza's would appear - one row for each pizza that the person has.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: First, Welcome to SO! Second, you might want to see the [FAQ]:www.stackoverflow.com/faq for how to better structure your question to get a good answer on this site. That said, it's kind of hard to help you except say `Yes` to your question `Is there a way to do this?` I will go a step further and offer that it will almost certainly require some VBA code for this kind of call and response type application in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code you'll want is `EntireRow.Insert`, so read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714831/inserting-rows-without-selecting-anything) to get you started. It should be fairly straightforward to apply the value put into a specific cell to quantify how many rows you want inserted below the row in question.